# Module not found error while python file is in same folder

Tags: python, import, databricks, sys, modulenotfounderror

I am currently working in Databricks and trying to run code from https://github.com/google/automl/tree/master/efficientdet#7-eval-on-coco-2017-val-or-test-dev%5Befficientdet%5D(https://stackoverflow.com)

I am trying to create a tfrecord from coco data.

Now this is what the directory looks like where I am working in:

```
.
├── Det-AdvProp.md
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── aug
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── autoaugment.py
│   ├── autoaugment_test.py
│   ├── gridmask.py
│   ├── gridmask_test.py
│   ├── mosaic.py
│   └── mosaic_test.py
├── backbone
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── backbone_factory.py
│   ├── efficientnet_builder.py
│   ├── efficientnet_builder_test.py
│   ├── efficientnet_lite_builder.py
│   ├── efficientnet_lite_builder_test.py
│   ├── efficientnet_model.py
│   └── efficientnet_model_test.py
├── coco_metric.py
├── coco_metric_test.py
├── dataloader.py
├── dataloader_test.py
├── dataset
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── create_coco_tfrecord.py  <-- I am running this file
│   ├── create_coco_tfrecord_test.py  
│   ├── create_pascal_tfrecord.py
│   ├── create_pascal_tfrecord_test.py
│   ├── inspect_tfrecords.py
│   ├── label_map_util.py   <-- And the file above is trying to import this file
│   └── tfrecord_util.py
```

I am running this command.

```
!PYTHONPATH=".:$PYTHONPATH"  python dataset/create_coco_tfrecord.py \
    --image_dir=val2017 \
    --object_annotations_file=annotations/instances_val2017.json \
    --output_file_prefix=tfrecord/val \
    --num_shards=32
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/driver/automl/efficientdet/dataset/create_coco_tfrecord.py", line 42, in <module>
    from dataset import label_map_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataset'
```

## Try 1

I have tried to append the parent directory to sys.path.

```
sys.path.append("/databricks/driver/automl/efficientdet/dataset/..")
```

This didn't help at all. Still got the same error.

## Try 2

```
from .dataset import label_map_util
```

This resulted in this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/driver/automl/efficientdet/dataset/create_coco_tfrecord.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .dataset import label_map_util
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

## Try 3

I've checked that I am running the command in the "dataset" directory

That doesn't change anything as well

## Try 4

I have also checked with os.getcwd() what the working directory is.

```
/databricks/driver/automl/
```

## Any other solutions?

If someone would know other things one could try, i'd appreciate it!

Comment: Do the contents of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgCVIa5qQhM) clarify your problem?

Comment: Thank you @Clasherkasten. That video is definitely handy and I'll add it to my arsenal of fighting the "module not found" error ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it had to do with the working directory of `create_coco_tfrecord.py` file. Even though I changed my working directory to `/databricks/driver/automl/efficientdet/dataset/` in databricks itself, it didn't change it for the `create_coco_tfrecord.py` file.

So when checking the current working directory in `create_coco_tfrecord.py` using `os.getcwd()`. I got `/databricks/driver/automl/`.

So when python tries to run `from dataset import label_map_util` it couldn't find the module because there isn't a "dataset" directory in `/databricks/driver/automl/`

The dataset directory is in `/databricks/driver/automl/efficientdet` directory

So the solution the my problem is to change it to `from efficient.dataset import label_map_util`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this when you are in the create_coco_tfrecord? Maybe this code piece can solve. :

`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..')))`

Then you should run your script when you are in the dataset folder.